# Creating file and saving in Django model (AttributeError?)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a huge string that I want to save as a file in a Django model. In order to do that, I have written the following code:

```
with open("new_file", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(myString)
    outfile.close()


my_obj = Model_Type(obj_name = name, my_file = outfile)
my_obj.save()
```

This raises an error,

> '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '_committed'

But after searching online for solutions, I've come to a dead end. Any advice will be gratefully appreciated!

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/dbkarga/6/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.1 Python Version: 3.6.1 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'app.apps.AppConfig'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in
>   inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in
>   _wrapped_view
>     23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "\venv\project\app\views.py" in dbkarga
>     93.                 app.postgis2geojson.getData(gis_id, db_name, db_user, db_pass, db_addr, db_port, t)
>
> File "\venv\project\app\postgis2geojson.py" in getData
>     119.    my_obj.save()
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
>     806.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
>     836.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
>     922.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
>     961.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in
>   manager_method
>     85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   _insert
>     1061.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   execute_sql
>     1098.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   as_sql
>     1051.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   
>     1051.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   
>     1050.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   pre_save_val
>     1000.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
>
> File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in
>   pre_save
>     295.         if file and not file._committed:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /app/dbkarga/6/ Exception Value:
>   '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: Can you please post the entire traceback of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I see your problem now.

Outfile must be an instance of either `django.core.files.File` or `django.core.files.base.ContentFile` (see manual [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) for details).

The two choices you can use are:

```
# Using File
outfile = open('/path/to/file')
my_obj = Model_Type(obj_name = name, my_file = File(outfile))
# Using ContentFile
my_obj = Model_Type(obj_name = name, my_file = ContentFile('Your very long string goes here'))
```

Updated with how to read the file

```
f = Model_Type.objects.all().get(id=0).my_file 
f.open(mode='rb') 
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Comment: Amazing suggestion! ContentFile seems to be just what I need. However, I do have one more concern. It works fine, but when I use the admin site, the objects seem to have no file attached. Is using a FileField in the model correct? How can my app read what has been uploaded? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: When executing the code you suggested, I get the error "my_file has no file associated with it". Any ideas why? Thanks once again :)

Comment: Hmm. Can you post a new question with the traceback for this error?

Comment: Here you go, thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756603/contentfile-not-saved-in-django-model-filefield